# how to enable sql authentication mode via cmd while installing SQLEXPR_x64_ENU?

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, authentication, cmd

I am trying to install SQLEXPR_x64_ENU via cmd via a batch file as follows:

```
 SETUP.EXE /ACTION=Install UIMODE=Normal /QUIET=True /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=True /InstanceId=SQLSERVERFINAL /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=@123 /InstanceName=SQLSERVERFINAL /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=True /UpdateEnabled=False
```

Then via sql management studio tried connecting to SQLSERVERFINAL instance keeping sql authentication mode enabled and for the feild server name: domain/user and password:@123, but it did not connected. If i connect using windows authentication connections gets successfull.Then in the .bat file i added additinal two parameters "/SQLSVCACCOUNT=xyz/user /SQLSVCPASSWORD=@123" as follows:

```
SETUP.EXE /ACTION=Install UIMODE=Normal /QUIET=True /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=True /InstanceId=SQLSERVERFINAL /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=@123 /InstanceName=SQLSERVERFINAL /SQLSVCACCOUNT=xyz/user /SQLSVCPASSWORD=@123 /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=True /UpdateEnabled=False
```

But still i am not able to login via sql authentication mode. So suggest me how shall i enable the option of sql authentication via commands in the .bat file, windows authentication is successfull its just not enabling sql authentication mode via .bat file.

Comment: `/SQLSVCACCOUNT` is the name of the (Windows) account SQL Server should run under, not the name of an account you can use to connect. `/SECURITYMODE=SQL` is what is enabling SQL authentication. `/SAPWD` sets the password for the built-in `sa` account. SQL authentication is already enabled. You should log in with your current account (since `/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN` is also specified), give `sa` a strong password, and create any SQL accounts you want.